# Algorithm not getting into if condition (Sherlock and the Valid String)

Tags: c

I am basically trying to solve [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-valid-string/problem) challenge. This is my code:

```
int arr[26]={0};
    int freq=0;
    int deletion=0;
    
    for(int i=0;i!='\0';i++)
    {
        arr[s[i]-'a']++;
    }
 
    
    freq=arr[0];
    for(int i=1;i<26;i++)
    {
        if(freq!=arr[i])
        {
            deletion++;
            return "HAHA";
        }
    }

    if(deletion>1)
    {
        return "NO";
    }
    else 
    {
        return "YES";
    }
```

I realized it wasn't getting into the deletion++, and then I used a return "HAHA" to make sure of it.
For some reason, the condition `freq!=arr[i]` never gets satisfied, even when the content of the freq and arr[i] are different. I guess I am getting trapped in a very silly mistake here.

Comment: Take a closer look at `for(int i=0;i!='\0';i++)`....

Comment: May be you should use spaces to make your code more readable...?

Comment: Like this: `for( int i=0; i != '\0'; i++)`

Comment: Why don't you simply debug the code? Add printf statements, at the very least, to show what is executing and what the key variable values are at each step.

Answer (score 0):

This line has a problem:

```c
for(int i=0;i!='\0';i++)
```

`\0` is actually a null-terminator. Probably you meant this:

```c
for(int i = 0; i != size_of_array_s; i++)
```

**OR:**

```c
for(int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
```

Answer (score -1):

this line is a problem in line
for(int i=0;i!='\0';i++)

Comment: As well as pointing out the problem, your answer should also offer a solution (as the other answer already has).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).